# org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: No response after timeout: 60000

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I'm getting the following error in some of my Solr queries:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: No response after timeout: 60000
```

Where do I change this timeout value? I didn't see any relevant setting in solrconfig.xml

(Yes, I know that the query is slow and that I should probably look at improving the performance. But right now, I'm only concerned about the accuracy of the results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your DSE version and actual config, but if you're using the latest DSE and the netty shard transport it's: netty_client_request_timeout.